# Can custom 403 page when denied by GAE firewall

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to display page only client via specific IP addr.
So, I set GAE filewall on GCP Console > AppEngine > Firewall.

But GAE FW shows google's 403 page to denied user.
I want to show my 403 page to denied user.
Can custom 403 page if GAE firewall deny?

note:
The page is static_file.So, it can't check IP-Addr on Server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that's possible: the firewall prevents the request from even reaching the point where your `app.yaml` config is parsed - the only place where you can configure custom error pages, via the `error_handlers` row in the [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#syntax) table.